# MongoDB Query interrupted when processing bulk records

Tags: node.js, mongodb

What will happen when my Mongodb query running on bulk records is interrupted by a power outage or sudden powering down of the system or a nodeJS application server?
How to rollback from the damage if any from the incident?

Comment: How are you doing the bulk processing of records?

Comment: I am finding the records using the _id and then updating them with a value. eg: db.getCollection("records").update({_id: ObjectId},{$set:{property:value}},{multi:true})

Comment: Are you using MongoDB 4.0? and are you working with a sharded cluster?

Comment: No. It's a basic query with the default MongoDB setup.

Comment: Basically, I want to prevent partial updation of data to the database by rollingback previous query or completing the processing after the mongodb server is started again.

Answer (score 0):

If you're running MongoDB 4.0 and not within a sharded environment you can use transactions so you'll get an all or nothing effect.

https://docs.mongodb.com/master/core/transactions/

It's fairly simple:

- Create session
- Start transaction
- Do work
- Commit transaction